# What is the most efficient and Performant way of redirect http:// to https:// in node.js [Conceptual point of view.]

Tags: node.js

```
// set up plain http server
var http = express.createServer();

// set up a route to redirect http to https
http.get('*',function(req,res){  
res.redirect('https://example.com'+req.url)
})

// have it listen on 8080
http.listen(8080);
```

It's Manageable but It would be nice, if someone share the core node.js point of view.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only listen for https requests with `express`, and add a simple HTTP server listener for redirection like such:

```js
let server = require('http');
server.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(302, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Location': 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.url
  });
  res.end('<h1>Redirecting...</h1>');
}).listen(80);
```

```